# Android:source code of startlescan

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I need to see how the method startlescan() in android api  is acessing the phone bluetooth to start scanning.where can i find the source code of startlescan().and also what is the scan interval of ble in smartphones.

Answer (score 1):

Next time you can use google.

The sources are [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.L_preview/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.java#BluetoothAdapter.startLeScan%28android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback%29).

Comment: codemonkey i already have that but i couldnt find how startlescan() is accesing the bluetooth hw .i meant the source code for startlescan()!

Comment: Have you clicked on my link? There is the source code of `public boolean startLeScan(UUID[] serviceUuids, LeScanCallback callback)` of the `BluetoothAdapter` class.